# Scroll: auto not working in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, scroll

Anybody help me, i have a website: http://sugo.vn/Tin-tuc and my scroll: auto not working in IE8

My css:

```
.div_over {
     float: right;
     height: 345px;
     max-width: 98%;
     min-width: 98%;
     overflow: auto;
     width: 98%;
     padding: 0px 7px; }

ul.list_news, ul.list_tuyendung {
    list-style: none outside none;
    position: inherit;
    width: 100%;
}

ul.list_news li, ul.list_tuyendung li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 99%;
}
```

Bind data

```
 div class="div_over">
    <asp:Panel ID="PNListNews" runat="server">
        <ul class="list_news">
           <asp:Repeater ID="DTLListNews" runat="server">
               <ItemTemplate>
                  <li>
                     <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImageSmall")%>' ToolTip='<%#Eval("Title")%>' />
                     <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtListNews" CommandName="details" CssClass="list_new" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id")%>' runat="server"><%#Eval("Title")%></asp:LinkButton>
                     <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Title")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                  </li>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
   </asp:Panel>
 </div>
```

I have searched but some solution not work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

pre 
{
    max-height: none\9 
}

won't validate, but should work in ie8 standards